# How to sort and filter data in "table" and "tabulate" in Stata

Tags: sorting, stata, summary

Commands `tab x` and `table x` returns summary stats sorted by `x`.

Is there a way to **sort and filter** tables of summary statistics by summary statistics, such as means and frequencies?

For example, I would like to have a table of means sorted by means.

There is a combination of `collapse` and then `sort` for that, but they replace the dataset in memory.

Is the answer provided by Nick the only option: [Stata: Summary stats with table. Order by N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595647/stata-summary-stats-with-table-order-by-n)?

Comment: Best to show sample code that you have tried and use a reproducible example. Your specific needs are unclear to me.

Comment: I know of no one-shot command to do what you want in general. In general, a variable containing what you want to show and a variable defining order of categories are sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick solved your problem in his earlier answer.  The crucial line  was:

```
gsort -n
```

which sorted by descending values of the count variable.  Change the "n" to any of the other statistics and you will sort by that statistic. Here's a sort by descending values of the mean.

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
gen make2 = substr(make,1, strpos(make," ")-2)
replace make2 = make if missing(make2)
collapse (count)n=price (mean)mean=price (p50)median=price (sd)sd=price ///
(min)min=price (max)max=price, by(make2)
gsort -mean
format mean-max %9.2f
format n %9.0f
list make2  mean  n median sd min max, sep(0) noobs
```